# Scope of sessionStorage and localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage, sessionstorage

I read some documentation on sessionStorage and localStorage, but I don't understand what the scope is: the domain, a specific page?

For example, if I have the following pages:

http://example.com/products.aspx?productID=1

http://example.com/products.aspx?productID=2

http://example.com/services.aspx?serviceID=3

And if on each of the above pages I run (with idvalue being the value in the querystring):

```
localStorage.setItem('ID',idvalue);
```

Am I going to end up with 3 different values stored, or are the values going to overwrite each other?

Answer (score 105, accepted):

The values are going to overwrite each other. Each key-name pair is unique for a protocol and domain, regardless of the paths.

The affected domain can be changed via the `document.domain` property.

- `sub.example.com` -> `example.com` is possible (subdomain)
- `sub.example.com` -> `other.example.com` is not possible

References:

- [MDN: Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API): "sessionStorage maintains a separate storage area for each given origin [...]"
- [MDN: Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin): "Two objects have the same origin only when the scheme, hostname, and port all match."

Comment: Thanks! Would you have a reference to recommend, that explains localStorage in detail?

Comment: @Christophe [MDN: Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage) and [W3c: Web Storage](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/).

Comment: well, even after reading the MDN page I still can't find the answer to my question... Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: @Christophe I have verified my statements a while back by viewing the sqlite(3) database called `webappsstore.sqlite` in my Firefox profile directory, using query `SELECT scope FROM webappsstore2;`. The result is the reverse of the domain, followed by the non-reversed protocol, and sufficed with the port, eg: `gro.allizom.snodda.secivres.:https:443`. As you can see, there's no mention of any path.

Comment: Here's documentation of the `document.domain` API mentioned: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/browsers.html#relaxing-the-same-origin-restriction

Comment: The [MDN: Web Storage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) doc does now specify: "sessionStorage maintains a separate storage area for each given origin [...]", where the "origin" is as defined here: [MDN: Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Origin) - i.e. sessionStorage and localStorage are partitioned by `scheme + hostname + port`

Answer (score 165):

**Session Storage:**

1. Values persist only as long as the window or tab in which they stored.
2. Values are only visible within the window or tab that created them.

**Local Storage:**

1. Values persist window and browser lifetimes.
2. Values are shared across every window or tab running at the same origin.

So, by reading and understanding this each key-value pair is unique for each domain, because local storage persist values across window or tab.

Comment: Thanks. Could you share the link to this reference?

Comment: Link above is now Defunct this is another great resource: http://www.sitepoint.com/an-overview-of-the-web-storage-api/

Comment: The conclusion may be correct, but not the reasoning. Even if the storage were per-page, it could still persist across windows/tabs.