# Best way to pass a single-use value between requests using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, history.js, html5-history

I need to trigger a page reload, via JS, preserving the vertical scroll position.

I'm using the solution described in [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17642872/refresh-page-and-keep-scroll-position):

1. Calculate the current scroll position
2. Add the current position as a querystring argument, then redirect
3. When the page reloads, read the value from the querystring & adjust the scroll pos

However, **I only want to restore the scroll position on that FIRST redirect**. If the user scrolls around the page and then triggers a **manual** reload using Ctrl-R, I do NOT want to re-scroll to that saved position.

Is there some way of passing a single-use, visible-to-the-next-request-only value using ONLY JavaScript? Or from removing a value from `document.location.href` *without* redirecting?

Should I be using the HTML 5 History API to "clear" the position value after I've consumed it?

Comment: My first thought is to use a cookie/session to store that variable, then delete it after you've used it.

Comment: @Populus, I thought about using cookies too but can't use a fixed cookie name, else I might run into issues if one user has multiple tabs open to different pages, each trying to use this feature. Though just like w/ localStorage I suppose I could use the full URL to generate a unique cookie name to avoid collisions.

Comment: how about if you didn't refresh the entire page, but just the portion that needs refreshing?

Comment: @Populus that's the long term goal, but in this particular case I do need a full page refresh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the value to sessionStorage. Once you use it, delete the value so it cannot be read on a manual refresh.

```
sessionStorage.setItem("scroll_position", "300");
sessionStorage.getItem("scroll_position"); // 300
sessionStorage.removeItem("scroll_position");
```

sessionStorage [is really well-supported](http://caniuse.com/namevalue-storage) -- it'll will work fine for IE8+ any relevant version of the other browsers.

---

StackOverflow handles after-page-load scrolling by storing post id's in the URL hash. You could do that as well.

The url [stackoverflow.com/...../21485393#21485393](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21485306/best-way-to-pass-a-single-use-value-between-requests-using-javascript/21485393#21485393) has #21485393 which matches an anchor element `<a name="21485393"></a>` It will automatically scroll to that element after the page loads.

You could do something like that as well.

```
http://your.url.com/page#300
```

Retrieve it with

```
window.location.hash
```

And remove it once you're done by

```
window.location.hash = ""
```

Comment: Was halfway through suggesting the same thing!

Comment: localStorage is awesome. It's so widely supported... such ninja

Comment: I thought about localStorage but thought it was a per-browser store, not a per-browser-tab store, which means I might have issues if users have multiple tabs open. I suppose I could just use the full URL when building a key...

Comment: edited my answer. Use sessionStorage instead. It's a localStorage instance that is unique to tabs/windows (even of the same url) and works exactly like localStorage. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742395/scope-of-sessionstorage-and-localstorage

Comment: even better! And yeah, can't believe IE8 supports it!