# Angularjs sessionStorage and scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Anyone know why my scope variables aren't being updated? It's mind boggling to me. The sessionStorage variables are fine but when I define them within scope variables.. I get 'undefined' errors. I've tinkered with $scope.$apply but apparently the scope is already being digested...:S please help a newbie out.

```
  if(sessionStorage.loggedIn){

    $scope.user = sessionStorage.user;  
    $scope.user.gravatar = sessionStorage.gravatar;
    console.log($scope.user.gravatar);
    console.log('Session variable is active');
    $scope.loggedIn = sessionStorage.loggedIn;

  }
```

the full code:

```
app.controller('loginCtrl', ['$scope','$route','Auth','$modal','$timeout', function($scope,$route,Auth,$modal,$timeout){

  if(sessionStorage.loggedIn){

    $scope.user = sessionStorage.user;  
    $scope.user.gravatar = sessionStorage.gravatar;
    console.log($scope.user.gravatar);
    console.log('Session variable is active');
    $scope.loggedIn = sessionStorage.loggedIn;

  }

  $scope.login = function(){
    Auth.save({
      'username': $scope.username,
      'password': $scope.password
    },function(data) {
      $scope.loggedIn = true;
      $scope.user = data.user;
      $scope.user.gravatar = data.gravatar;

      sessionStorage.loggedIn = $scope.loggedIn;
      sessionStorage.user = data.user; 
      sessionStorage.gravatar = data.gravatar;
      $route.reload();

    },function(response){
      $scope.flash = response.data.flash;   
      $scope.pop = true;    
      $timeout(function(){$scope.pop = false;}, 3000);
    })

  };

  $scope.logout = function (){
    Auth.get({},function(){  
      delete sessionStorage.user;
      delete sessionStorage.gravatar;
      delete sessionStorage.loggedIn;
      $scope.loggedIn = false;
      $timeout(function(){$route.reload();}, 1000);
    })
  };


}]);
```

Summary of chain of events:

1) User logs in

2) Upon successful login, the user's details (json object) are stored in `sessionStorage.user = data.user` and the data.user variable typically contains this sort of info `{id: 1, username: "user123", firstname: "", lastname: "", email: "username@gmail.com"}`
-the user's gravatar hash is also stored in a sessionStorage.user.gravatar variable.

3) If user logs out, sessionStorage variables are deleted.

4) However, if user is still logged in, refreshes/reloads the page (from browser), the sessionStorage variable is still active, and still contains the data, *BUT* for some reason, when I set scope variables eg. `$scope.user = sessionStorage.user`--the scope variable remains undefined--despite sessionStorage.user being perfectly viable. The issue appears to be with the scope.

Comment: Are you sure the sessionStorage.user is an object?

Comment: can you specify the chain of events you are invoking and what the behavior you're expecting should be

Comment: can you get this into a jsfiddle, jsbin, or plunker? also important may be what browser you are using

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742395/scope-of-sessionstorage-and-localstorage

Comment: @JimmyRare yes, I can confirm it is an json object eg. `{id: 1, username: "user123", firstname: "", lastname: "", email: "username@gmail.com"}`

Comment: @Maslow Sorry, it's going to be tricky to put it into a jsFiddle..I will do as adrichman suggested, which is to specify the chain of events

Comment: This line is absolutely updating a scope variable: `$scope.user = sessionStorage.user`. It may be that the value you are setting it to is undefined. Or that when you check the value on the scope, you're accessing a different scope. Try printing `sessionStorage.user` to the console, before doing the assignment to the scope variable. Try printing `$scope.$id` to the console before the assignment, and then print out the $id where ever it is you are seeing the problem ... Are they the same? You can debug this! :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to serialize your user object to JSON before storing on sessionStorage, because it is implemented as a collection of string values.

Try something like this

```
 sessionStorage.user = JSON.stringify($scope.user);
```

and then

```
 $scope.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.user);
```

Comment: Sidenote: There is [`angular.fromJson( json );`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.fromJson) also.

Answer (score 6):

Nowadays angularjs don't have the JSON.stringify just assign the $scope values in sessionStorage

```
$sessionStorage.user = $scope.user;
```

[For Detailed documentation on $sessionStorage service](http://AngularJS%20-%20$sessionStorage%20by%20Scriptwerx%20is%20a%20service%20for%20use%20in%20your%20AngularJS%20applications.)

AngularJS - $sessionStorage by Scriptwerx is a service for use in your AngularJS applications.

`npm install --save-dev angular-swx-session-storage`