# Token not getting saved in $window.sessionStorage when page is opened in different browser

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies, token

I'm initializing the token that is generated after I log in to my application in $window.sessioStorage .

```
var token = this.$window.sessionStorage["apiKey"];
```

But this token seem to be undefined when I copy the url(after log in ) and open in different browser.I'm redirected back to the login page.
Does $window.sessionStorage holds the values of variables in the same browser window?Or what could be another way to retain the value of token even if I opened the page in different browser window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the right behaviour

> The sessionStorage property allows you to access a session Storage
>   object. sessionStorage is similar to localStorage, the only difference
>   is while data stored in localStorage has no expiration set, data
>   stored in sessionStorage gets cleared when the page session ends. A
>   page session lasts for as long as the browser is open and survives
>   over page reloads and restores. Opening a page in a new tab or window
>   will cause a new session to be initiated.

You can keep information even if the browser is closed and reopend another time by using `localStorage`, but, as I said, if you open other browser you'll have to set items agains.

Local storage examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API/Using_the_Web_Storage_API)

Code example :

```
// set something in localStorage
localStorage.setItem('bgcolor', 'green');


// get something from localStorage
localStorage.getItem('bgcolor') // it will output green
```

Comment: Then I will loose the variable value.That's what you are trying to say @Kosmo ?

Comment: Yes !  sessionStorage keeps values until you close page/browser and it's not transmited between browsers

Comment: So what is the solution if I want to transmit or hold the value irrespective of  the browser usages?

Comment: You can not do that. Each browser stores data separately ( has its own implementation ).   You can use some server side technology and a database to store information and when someone is making a request to your page you check in your database and if you have that information there  and in this case you set  localStorage/sessionStorage in your client app and redirect to wanted page.

Comment: Ok. Leave about different browsers.Can I have this functionality in same browser with different tabs opened?

Comment: As I quoted in the answer above, yes, but use localStorage instead of sessionStorage( which is per page/tab ). I've updated my answer with a link to some examples