# Is it possible to use localstorage with context per path like cookie?

Tags: javascript, html, local-storage

Aware of issues like:

- Cookies are included with every HTTP request, thereby slowing down
  your web application by needlessly transmitting the same data over
  and over
- Cookies are included with every HTTP request, thereby    sending data
  unencrypted over the internet (unless your entire web    application
  is served over SSL)
- Cookies are limited to about 4 KB of    data —    enough to slow down
  your application (see above), but not    enough    to be terribly
  useful

(from: http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

I decided to use localstorage instead of cookies.

**QUESTION:** Can I limit localstorage context to certain path like with cookies?

Comment: Storage is per origin. But it's standard to namespace your variables : `localStorage['moduleA.a']` which helps manage big sites (or origins with many different sites).

Comment: I found some info here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742395/scope-of-sessionstorage-and-localstorage

Comment: I would not care on 4Kb of transmitting data in year 2014. Each of those has [diff purposes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220660/local-storage-vs-cookies)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments already, webstorages (`localStorage`, `sessionStorage`) are scoped per origin.

> User agents must have a set of local storage areas, one for each origin.

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/#the-localstorage-attribute

---

## What is an origin?

Let's just quote the w3.org wiki page on the same origin policy:

> An origin is defined by the scheme, host, and port of a URL.

Source: http://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy

Answer (score 0):

Use some fresh Library!

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pathstorage

I was agony for the same subject. And I choose solution "made my own". :)