# Selective ejs template based on user selected environment

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs, hexo

I am building a hexo blog theme in ejs, which will style my technical docs project. I want to allow the user to select a language (JavaScript or TypeScript). I would then like to type code snippets something like :

````
{% js %}
```JavaScript
var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
```
{% endjs %}

{% ts %}
```TypeScript
import geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
```
{% endts %}
````

Then two button / a slider so the user could choose typescript or javascript (which would default to js). I am comfortable with the UI implementation, but am not sure how I would set a property to determine which of the above snippets is used?

and depending on which language the user had selected, the correct snippet would display. How could I implement this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine that the output of your Hexo tags is something like this.

```html
<div>
  <div class="codeblock js">
    var geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
  </div>
  <div class="codeblock ts">
    import geolocation = require("nativescript-geolocation");
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, you have to write javascript to :

- Display code blocks by default (default language)
- Display code blocks in the desired language when a button is clicked
- Save the selected language to display the right language when a page is refreshed or changed

Here is an example with jQuery library in a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LouisBarranqueiro/a573s3zs/) because session storage is not allowed in snippet on SO

In this example, I used `.hide()` and `.show()` method but you can also use CSS class to do this. Add a class (`.addClass()`) on desired language code blocks, and remove class (`.removeClass()`) on other code blocks with some css :

```css
.codeblock {
  display:none;
}
.codeblock.active {
  display:block;
}
```

Comment: Would Session-Storage be site-wide or just per-page?

Comment: session or local storage scope is domain and subdomain. read http://stackoverflow.com/a/9784994/3755845 for more information :)

Comment: Is it possible to modify this to use `<input></input>` tags rather than `<button></button>` tags?

Comment: yeah, of course use `<input type="button" value="Javascript"/>`.