# Does HTML5 session storage persist after redirects when redirected back to original domain?

Tags: session, session-storage, web-storage

I'm using auth0 for authentication, so when authenticating the user will be redirected to another domain, the auth0 domain, and then redirected back to my web application.

If I save something on session storage before the user clicks on the authentication link, will that value still be there when the user is redirected back to my app, assuming the user is still in the same window and tab?

Comment: I believe you can find the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9742395/scope-of-sessionstorage-and-localstorage

Comment: For what it's worth, if anybody else thinks the other questions' answers isn't completely clear on this, it DOES persist if you go to a different domain and then come back.

Comment: It seems to me that the linked question and answer is confusing localStorage with sessionStorage.  So I actually tried it out myself and confirmed that both will persist in the scenario in this question.  Commenting in case anybody else reads the linked question and is not convinced!