# Detect if page is already open when authenticating via magic email link

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

[Firebase/auth docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/email-link-auth) explain well how to login via magic email link. Issue that I have is that magic email link is opened in a new tab/window which means that after a successful authentication I have two tabs open. What is the best practice to close new/old window/tab if there is already one open?

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use localStorage API to check for this condition. See this question on how to use it: [JavaScript: sharing data between tabs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1366483/javascript-sharing-data-between-tabs)

From UX standpoint: while closing a duplicate tab seems like a good idea on a first glance, as a user I'd not be too happy about losing a tab with it's back history. I've seen at least one website that applied a whole-page overlay saying "this is open already in another tab" to disable interaction.

Comment: I would not close the old tab but the new one. I was thinking of using localStorage API but had two edge cases why I was not sure about it: 1) what happens if user first closes manually the tab and than opens the new link? Than I would have to listen to `beforeunload` event and clear the key. 2) What if I already have two or more tabs open and I was to implement the strategy from the point 1). Than I would have to add onchange listener to localStorage, and it quickly blows out. I was kind of hoping for some straightforward/simple solution.

Comment: Instead of clearing the key, you can periodically set a value to current timestamp. Kind of. It's not a trivial problem to solve. Some websites delegate to service workers. They are shared across all tabs in a domain. That serves as a good guarantee as well.